# Subset dataframe in R based on a list specified in a vector (using a 'starts with' expression or equivalent)

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, subset, startswith

I am trying to identify any participant taking statins in a dataset of over 1 million rows and subset based on this. I have a vector that includes all the codes for these medications (I've just made a few up for demonstration purposes), and I would next like to create a function that searches through the dataframe and identifies any case that has a medication code that "starts with" any of the characters listed in the df. 
The df looks like this:

```
     ID readcode_1 readcode_2 generic_name
1  1001       bxd1 1146785342  Simvastatin
2  1002       <NA>       <NA>         <NA>
3  1003       <NA>       <NA>  Pravastatin
4  1004       <NA>       <NA>         <NA>
5  1005       bxd4   45432344         <NA>
6  1006       <NA>       <NA>         <NA>
7  1007       <NA>       <NA>         <NA>
8  1008       <NA>       <NA>         <NA>
9  1009       <NA>       <NA>         <NA>
10 1010       bxde       <NA>         <NA>
11 1011       <NA>       <NA>         <NA>
```

Ideally, I'd like the end product to look like this:

```
     ID readcode_1 readcode_2 generic_name
1  1001       bxd1 1146785342  Simvastatin
3  1003       <NA>       <NA>  Pravastatin
5  1005       bxd4   45432344         <NA>
10 1010       bxde       <NA>         <NA>
```

Here is my code so far (doesn't currently work)

```
#create vector with list of medication codes of interest
medications <- c("bxd", "Simvastatin", "1146785342", "45432344", "Pravastatin")

# look through all columns (apart from IDs in first column) and if any of them start with the codes listed in the medications vector, return a 1
df$statin_prescribed <- apply(df[, -1], 1, function(x) {
  if(any(x %in% startsWith(x, medications))) {
    return(1)
  } else {
    return(0)
  }
})

# subset to include only individuals prescribed statins
df <- subset(df, statin_prescribed == 1)
```

The part that doesn't seem to work is `startsWith(x, statin)`.

Please let me know if you have any suggestions and additional, whether there is alternative code that may be more time efficient!

Comment: Can you give us an example of `df` before and after? Also, I don't see where `medications` is used in `apply`. Maybe `statin` should be `medications`?

Comment: One more thing: `startsWith` returns a logical vector, e.g. `startsWith(c("blah", "klah"), "b")` returns `[1]  TRUE FALSE`, so it doesn't really make sense to ask R if `x` is in there somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a solution using the `dplyr` package

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  filter_at(vars(-ID), any_vars(grepl(paste(medications, collapse = "|"), .)))
```

Small explanation: we are asking to `filter` all those rows where at least one variable (excluding `ID`) starts with one of the values inside `medications`

Output

```
#     ID readcode_1 readcode_2 generic_name
# 1 1001       bxd1 1146785342  Simvastatin
# 2 1003       <NA>       <NA>  Pravastatin
# 3 1005       bxd4   45432344         <NA>
# 4 1010       bxde       <NA>         <NA>
```

---

Another solution in base R with a similar rationale is the following

```
df[apply(df[,-1], 1, function(x) {any(grepl(paste(medications, collapse = "|"), x))}),]

Output is the same (except row index which I believe is not relevant)
#      ID readcode_1 readcode_2 generic_name
# 1  1001       bxd1 1146785342  Simvastatin
# 3  1003       <NA>       <NA>  Pravastatin
# 5  1005       bxd4   45432344         <NA>
# 10 1010       bxde       <NA>         <NA>
```

---

After some benchmarking tests, the base R solution seems to be around 5x faster than the `dplyr` one. So I suggest you to use the base R solution if time efficiency is your main concern.

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  df %>% filter_at(vars(-ID), any_vars(grepl(paste(medications, collapse = "|"), .))),
  df[apply(df[,-1], 1, function(x) {any(grepl(paste(medications, collapse = "|"), x))}),],
  times = 100
)

# Unit: microseconds
#                                                                                             # expr    min
#         df %>% filter_at(vars(-ID), any_vars(grepl(paste(medications,      collapse = "|"), .))) 1958.4
#  df[apply(df[, -1], 1, function(x) {     any(grepl(paste(medications, collapse = "|"), x)) }), ]  341.7
#       lq     mean  median      uq    max neval
#  1989.55 2146.993 2041.30 2149.05 7851.1   100
#   352.50  405.972  380.25  401.55 2154.0   100
```

Comment: Thank you! This works well although it has taken over 20 minutes to run! Any suggestions on making it more time efficient?

Comment: Well your dataset is quite large, so it's quite normal that it takes a bit.. But I will try to think of something more time efficient :)

Comment: @M_Oxford I've added a faster solution, feel free to check it out!