# Python: Searching through multiple columns and identifying rows that contain any of the elements in a list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, subset

I recently posted a question on how to subset using R: [Subset dataframe in R based on a list specified in a vector (using a 'starts with' expression or equivalent)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62195183/subset-dataframe-in-r-based-on-a-list-specified-in-a-vector-using-a-starts-wit)

User @Ric S very kindly provided the R answer to this question. 
The R solution is:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  filter_at(vars(-ID), any_vars(grepl(paste(medications, collapse = "|"), .)))
```

However, my impression is that Python may be more time efficient. Just to summarize, I am trying to identify any participant prescribed statins in a dataset of over 1 million rows and subset based on this. I have a list that includes all the codes for these medications (I've just made a few up for demonstration purposes), and I would next like to search through the dataframe and subset it to anyone who has a medication code that "starts with" **any** of the elements on the list. The loop seems redundant in the example, but I will be running this code for a few drug classes.

Example dataset, called `meds_df`:

```
     ID readcode_1 readcode_2 generic_name
1  1001       bxd1 1146785342  Simvastatin
2  1002       <NA>       <NA>         <NA>
3  1003       <NA>       <NA>  Pravastatin
4  1004       <NA>       <NA>         <NA>
5  1005       bxd4   45432344         <NA>
6  1006       <NA>       <NA>         <NA>
7  1007       <NA>       <NA>         <NA>
8  1008       <NA>       <NA>         <NA>
9  1009       <NA>       <NA>         <NA>
10 1010       bxde       <NA>         <NA>
11 1011       <NA>       <NA>         <NA>
```

with the expected output being:

```
     ID readcode_1 readcode_2 generic_name
1  1001       bxd1 1146785342  Simvastatin
3  1003       <NA>       <NA>  Pravastatin
5  1005       bxd4   45432344         <NA>
10 1010       bxde       <NA>         <NA>
```

My code so far based on other stackoverflow questions, I'll also need to embed any() or an equivalent here:

```
list_to_extract = ["bxd", "Simvastatin", "1146785342", "45432344", "Pravastatin"]
variable_list = ['statins']
for m in variable_list:
    print('extracting individuals prescribed %s' %m)
test = meds_df.loc[meds_df['readcode_1', 'readcode_2','generic_name'].str.startswith(list_to_extract, na=False)]
    print(test)
```

Error recieved:

```
KeyError: ('readcode_1', 'readcode_2','generic_name')
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try adding an extra set of brackets around your column names to index like so: `meds_df[['readcode_1', 'readcode_2','generic_name']].str.startswith( ... )`

Comment: @bug_spray unfortunately when you slice by list of columns, it'll return a DataFrame object which doesn't have the `str` methods available (until you get to the Series level, that is).

Comment: @r.ook You're right. I somehow overlooked that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the proper syntax is `meds_df[['readcode_1', 'readcode_2','generic_name']]` (`list` of column names in a index slice).  This is why you are getting a `KeyError`.

To answer your question, here is one way to accomplish it:

```
# Updated to use tuple per David's suggestion
idx = pd.concat((med_df[col].astype(str).str.startswith(tuple(list_to_extract)) for col in ['readcode_1', 'readcode_2','generic_name']), axis=1).any(axis=1)

med_df.loc[idx]
```

Result:

```
      ID readcode_1    readcode_2 generic_name
1   1001       bxd1  1.146785e+09  Simvastatin
3   1003        NaN           NaN  Pravastatin
5   1005       bxd4  4.543234e+07          NaN
10  1010       bxde           NaN          NaN
```

Comment: Nice answer! If you convert to tuple `list_to_extract` you actually don't need to iterate over it, but you can pass it directly to `startswith`

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with apply in this way:

```
list_to_extract = ["bxd", "Simvastatin", "1146785342", "45432344", "Pravastatin"]

bool_df = df[['readcode_1', 'readcode_2','generic_name']].apply(lambda x: x.str.startswith(tuple(list_to_extract), na=False), axis=1)

df.loc[bool_df[bool_df.any(axis=1)].index]
```

Output:

```
    ID  readcode_1  readcode_2  generic_name
1   1001    bxd1    1.146785e+09    Simvastatin
3   1003    NaN     NaN             Pravastatin
5   1005    bxd4    4.543234e+07    NaN
10  1010    bxde    NaN             NaN
```

*Thanks to r.ook for spotting a small mistake*

Comment: @sammywemmy You are right, I removed it from the answer, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution, where the string processing occurs within vanilla python before recreating the dataframe :

```
list_to_extract = ["bxd", "Simvastatin", "1146785342", "45432344", "Pravastatin"]

cols_to_search = ['readcode_1', 'readcode_2','generic_name']

output = [(ID, *searchbox) 
          for ID, searchbox in zip(df.ID,df.filter(cols_to_search).to_numpy())
          if any([str(box).startswith(tuple(list_to_extract)) for box in searchbox])]

pd.DataFrame(output, columns = df.columns)


     ID readcode_1  readcode_2  generic_name
0   1001    bxd1     1.146785e+09   Simvastatin
1   1003    NaN      NaN            Pravastatin
2   1005    bxd4     4.543234e+07   NaN
3   1010    bxde     NaN            NaN
```